# Are there error_code list?

Tags: cnosdb

As a web developer, I'm developing a project, which use cnosdb by http-request. For some security reasons, I have to hide the full error message. So I need to classify the error content. My problem is, Where can I find the error list of CnosDB?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Which errors do you mean, is https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/reference/rest_api.html#status-code what you are looking for?

Comment: I have added two examples in question. You can see that two different cnosdb-error has same http response code 422. And I want to classify the error_message in picture. Some I can return it to client and some not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a list of all the error codes. You can find some of the codes by looking at the source code, for example https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/blob/05573409a8887e071d66601bc793b32a6b9829f7/coordinator/src/errors.rs lists all of the `0500xx` codes. For some the message is directly included in the file, for others the message is included in another file that includes `errors.rs` (for example 050014 is defined at https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/blob/19db70776de9f10f7612f5bef44f81d5ffb148f4/coordinator/src/writer.rs#L223). For the errors of category 01, 02, 03 the code does not contain the numbers explicitly, instead the number is defined by the position in an `Enum`. To get a complete overview it would therefore be required to patch all these pieces of code together, which would be rather time-consuming.

However, a quick but incomplete list can be found by searching in the test cases. This produces the following list (cleaned/deduplicated manually by me):

```json
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Error during planning: Coercion from [Int64, Int64] to the signature Uniform(1, [Utf8, LargeUtf8, Binary, LargeBinary]) failed."}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Error during planning: failed to resolve tenant:cnosdb  db: createtable, table: test0"}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Error during planning: Inconsistent data type across values list at row 1 column 1"}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Error during planning: 'Int64 + Boolean' can't be evaluated because there isn't a common type to coerce the types to"}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Error during planning: Invalid function 'bit_and'"}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Error during planning: Projection references non-aggregate values: Expression m0.f0 could not be resolved from available columns: nullif(totimestamp(Int64(6636546679321595330)),totimestamp(Int64(8689896046418229165))), (- totimestamp(Int64(3346426503103871098)) IN (Map { iter: Iter([totimestamp(Int64(8796381831174491673)), totimestamp(Int64(7388672143893169360))]) })), SUM(ceil((- substr(m0.t0,Int64(5506560410096687103),Int64(-874633900)))))"}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Error during planning: Projections require unique expression names but the expression \"public.test.time\" at position 0 and \"public.test.time\" at position 3 have the same name. Consider aliasing (\"AS\") one of them."}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Error during planning: SELECT * with no tables specified is not valid"}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Error during planning: The function Sum does not support inputs of type Null."}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Internal error: Min/Max accumulator not implemented for type Boolean. This was likely caused by a bug in DataFusion's code and we would welcome that you file an bug report in our issue tracker"}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Internal error: Unsupported data type Ok(UInt64) for function to_timestamp_seconds. This was likely caused by a bug in DataFusion's code and we would welcome that you file an bug report in our issue tracker"}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Schema error: No field named 'f0'. Valid fields are 'key', 'value'."}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Schema error: No field named 'm0'.'t0'. Valid fields are 'SUM((- round(m0.f0)))'."}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: simplify_expressions\ncaused by\nInternal error: Optimizer rule 'simplify_expressions' failed due to unexpected error: Arrow error: Cast error: Cannot cast string '0.405601854465989730.5010374883053191' to value of Int64 type. This was likely caused by a bug in DataFusion's code and we would welcome that you file an bug report in our issue tracker"}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: This feature is not implemented: sql numeric literals in scientific notation are not supported"}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: This feature is not implemented: Unsupported CAST from Boolean to Timestamp(Nanosecond, None)"}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: This feature is not implemented: Unsupported value InList { expr: Nested(Nested(BinaryOp { left: Nested(Cast { expr: Value(Number(\"0.7382978061623816\", false)), data_type: String }), op: StringConcat, right: Nested(Cast { expr: Value(Boolean(false)), data_type: String }) })), list: [Value(SingleQuotedString(\"9sP䋛zqeoM\")), Value(SingleQuotedString(\"k*G\"))], negated: true } in a values list expression"}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: transform_bottom_func_to_topk_node\ncaused by\nInternal error: Optimizer rule 'transform_bottom_func_to_topk_node' failed due to unexpected error: Error during planning: 1. There cannot be nested selection functions. 2. There cannot be multiple selection functions., found: [\n    BOTTOM(m2.time, Int64(2)),\n    TOPK(m2.t0, Int64(3)),\n]. This was likely caused by a bug in DataFusion's code and we would welcome that you file an bug report in our issue tracker"}
{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: type_coercion\ncaused by\nInternal error: Optimizer rule 'type_coercion' failed due to unexpected error: Error during planning: 'Binary IS NOT DISTINCT FROM Utf8' can't be evaluated because there isn't a common type to coerce the types to. This was likely caused by a bug in DataFusion's code and we would welcome that you file an bug report in our issue tracker"}
{"error_code":"010002","error_message":"Arrow: Cast error: Cannot cast string '10a' to value of Float64 type"}
{"error_code":"010002","error_message":"Arrow: Divide by zero error"}
{"error_code":"010003","error_message":"Semantic error: Can not alter database precision"}
{"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: already have timestamp column"}
{"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: BOOLE is not a supported type"}
{"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: DEL is not valid encoding"}
{"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: expect codec encoding type in ()"}
{"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: Expected an SQL statement, found: c"}
{"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: Expected AS, found: NOTNULL"}
{"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: Expected end of statement, found: NOTNULL"}
{"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: Expected field columns when create table"}
{"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: Unterminated string literal at Line: 1, Column 36"}
{"error_code":"010027","error_message":"Semantic error: Field or Tag have the same name column1"}
{"error_code":"010028","error_message":"Semantic error:  column column7 already exists in table test0"}
{"error_code":"010029","error_message":"Semantic error: Column c not exists in table test_dps_table"}
{"error_code":"010030","error_message":"Semantic error: Can't drop tag column column7."}
{"error_code":"010032","error_message":"Semantic error: There must be at least one field column."}
{"error_code":"010033","error_message":"Semantic error: There must be at least one tag column. "}
{"error_code":"010034","error_message":"Semantic error: Tag does not support compression"}
{"error_code":"010035","error_message":"Semantic error: Column time does not support modification"}
{"error_code":"010036","error_message":"Semantic error: DB public conflict with table show_series.test"}
{"error_code":"010045","error_message":"Semantic error: Insert columns and Source columns not match"}
{"error_code":"010046","error_message":"Semantic error: SHOW SERIES does not support where clause contains field f1"}
{"error_code":"010061","error_message":"Tenant \"cnosdb\" forbid drop"}
{"error_code":"010062","error_message":"Database \"public\" forbid drop"}
{"error_code":"020002","error_message":"Fields can't be empty"}
{"error_code":"030017","error_message":"Database not found: \"cluster_schema\""}
{"error_code":"030019","error_message":"Table not found: \"cnosdb.createtable.test2\""}
{"error_code":"030020","error_message":"Table cnosdb.createtable.test0 already exists."}
{"error_code":"050014","error_message":"write expired time data not permit"}
```